# Command with variable number of arguments [*1 argument] + different behaviour depending on number of arguments and type of argument

Tags: macros, math-operators

I would like something that goes...
from this:

1. `\cmd{⟨x_1⟩}`
2. `\cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨x_2⟩}`
3. `\cmd{⟨y_1⟩}`
4. `\cmd{⟨y_1⟩,⟨y_2⟩}`
5. `\cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨y_1⟩}`
6. `\cmd{⟨x_1⟩,...,⟨x_n⟩,⟨y_1⟩}`
7. `\cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨y_1⟩,...,⟨y_n⟩}`
8. `\cmd{⟨x_1⟩,...,⟨x_n⟩,⟨y_1⟩,...,⟨y_m⟩}`

to this:

[image]

Otherwise something like: `\cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨z⟩}`, `\cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨x_2⟩,⟨z⟩}`, `\cmd{⟨z⟩,⟨y_1⟩}`, `\cmd{⟨z⟩,⟨y_1⟩,⟨y_2⟩}`
for 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively.

*The subscripts and the ellipsis aren't part of the inputs or outputs, nor are the angled brackets.

**Another example.
Something that goes from: `\command{Lapple Lbanana Rorgange}`
to: Apple, Banana `*` Orange. [Method 1]
Or from: `\command{apple banana * organge}`[Method 2]

Or where "apples" and "bananas" are defined in advance as going on the LHS and "organges" are defined as going on the right. [Method 3]

***I'm being asked to be more specific, also that strictly speaking this would be a command of one argument. I apologise for not being able to describe my question properly. Here are two types of things I would actually like to be able to achieve:
[image]

[image]

Comment: you can do this but the first form with `{}` breaks latex coding conventions, optional arguments should use `[]` the comma form is certainly the most natural latex syntax

Comment: your question is not at all clear, is the input just x or y going to A and B, what about other input? and when does the `*` go before and when after? The structure of 1 and 3 is identical but one has a postfix and one a prefix * ??

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity. I'm not entirely sure what I want or how I want to get there, in addition to the difficulty of specifying what I want. In regards to prefix/postfix, though, with the first form, the command would look at the input to see if it's an x or a y (x and y are just placeholders). In the second form, the position of `*` is made explicit in the command with z.

Comment: I would prefer it if x and y were different from A and B.

Comment: So in the first form, there would be two inputs types, say `⟨input_1⟩` and `⟨input_2⟩` and whether or not the corresponding output would be on the left-hand or the right-hand side of the star would be determined by their type.

Comment: although I posted an answer it looks to me now  like you only ever have one * and so you don't have a variable number of arguments at all, you simply have two arguments, each a list of tokens (possibly empty) and you put a * between them?

Comment: If I get it right, you have sequences of x-type-arguments and sequence of y-type-arguments. A sequence of x-type-arguments is to be trailed by a star. A sequence of y-type-arguments is to be preceded by a star. In case a sequence of x-type-args is trailed by a sequence of y-type-args, a single star both serves as the star trailing the x-type-argument-sequence and serves as the star preceding the y-type-argument-sequence. Is that correct? If so: How to handle arguments that are neither of x-type, nor of y-type? What interface do you wish for detecting what to consider x-type/y-type arguments?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. Only x-types and y-types would be entered, I think. I'm kind of agnostic/unsure of that and was open to any suggestions. For example, tagging each argument "L" or "R" to indicate whether it's to go on the left or right. Or explicitly putting in the star, so order tells you which is which — or defining certain "strings" (I'm not sure if that's the right word) in advance as belonging to the Left category or the Right category.

Answer (score 1):

You can define following TeX macros:

```
\def\cmd#1{$\def\cmdS{}\let\cmdX=\cmdXA \cmdA#1,⟨⟩,}
\def\cmdA⟨#1⟩,{%
   \ifx \relax#1\relax 
      \ifx\cmdX\cmdXA \Star\fi $%
   \else
      \isinunder#1_\iffalse \else \cmdX #1\end \fi
      \expandafter\cmdC
   \fi
}
\def\cmdXA #1#2_#3\end{%
   \ifx\relax#2\relax
      \ifx#1x\cmdS A_{#3}\def\cmdS{,}
      \else \ifx#1y\Star \let\cmdX=\cmdXB \def\cmdS{}\cmdX #1_#3\end \fi
   \fi\fi
}
\def\cmdXB #1#2_#3\end{%
   \ifx\relax#2\relax
      \ifx#1y\cmdS B_{#3}\def\cmdS{,}\fi
   \fi
}
\def\cmdC{\futurelet\next\cmdD}
\def\cmdD{\ifx.\next \expandafter\cmdDdots \else \expandafter\cmdA\fi}
\def\cmdDdots...,{,\dots \cmdA}
\def\isinunder#1_#2\iffalse{\ifx\relax#2\relax}
\def\Star{\mathrel{\star}}

%% test:

    \cmd{⟨x_1⟩}

    \cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨x_2⟩}

    \cmd{⟨y_1⟩}

    \cmd{⟨y_1⟩,⟨y_2⟩}

    \cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨y_1⟩}

    \cmd{⟨x_1⟩,...,⟨x_n⟩,⟨y_1⟩}

    \cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨y_1⟩,...,⟨y_n⟩}

    \cmd{⟨x_1⟩,...,⟨x_n⟩,⟨y_1⟩,...,⟨y_m⟩}

\cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨z⟩}; \cmd{⟨x_1⟩,⟨x_2⟩,⟨z⟩}; \cmd{⟨z⟩,⟨y_1⟩}; \cmd{⟨z⟩,⟨y_1⟩,⟨y_2⟩} 

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind typing stars explicitly you probably can do with a sequence of replacements:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\cmd{mmmmm}{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #5 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {x}{#1}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {y}{#2}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {*}{#3}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {,}{#4}
  \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{x_1*}\]

\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{x_1,x_2*}\]

\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{*y_1}\]

\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{*y_1,y_2}\]

\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{x_1*y_1}\]

\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{x_1,x_2,x_3*y_1}\]

\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{x_1*y_1,y_2,y_3}\]

\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{x_1,x_2,x_3*y_1,y_2,y_3}\]

\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{x_1,x_2,x_3*y_1,y_2,y_3*}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this does not suit you needs, then please provide a precise description of what you need.

Precise specifications of what is needed are a necessity for the development of so-called "clean code".

`\tl_replace_all:Nnn` does not work out if also things shall be replaced that are nested in curly braces.

The answer posted by egreg and since deleted, of course ;-) , yields results that look much better than what I propose.

But I'm not inclined to work my way through "pretty typesetting" and whatsoever subtle details as long as it is likely that via comments requirements will be "added" that lead to the need of changing or completely rewriting the code.

Comment: I apologise for the lack of clarity, I'm new to this and I wasn't really sure in my own mind what I wanted. I'm trying to abbreviate ultimately and I don't really know what the best way of going about it is.

Can I ask though why you included commas in your code? You've written the commas explicitly? As in `\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{,}{x_1,x_2*}\]`  

Otherwise, I think I can get your code pretty close to what I wanted, so thank you.

Comment: @BenLoewe  `\cmd{<replacement for letters x>}{<replacement for letters y>}{<replacement for stars>}{<replacement for commas>}{<argument where replacements shall take place>}`

Comment: but the commas aren't being replaced? It seems to work fine without `{<replacement for commas>}` and `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {,}{#4}`

Comment: @BenLoewe In my MWE the commas are replaced by commas, thus you don't notice. Try, e.g.,  `\[\cmd{A}{B}{\star}{Comma}{x_1,x_2,x_3*y_1,{y_2,y_3}*}\]` and you will see that commas are replaced by the phrase `Comma`. If you don't need the possibility of replacing commas, you of course can modify the macro not to take an argument for comma-replacement and not to replace commas.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterarate over a list of tokens something like this (I used `x` `y` `*` and `.` as the distinguished tokens here)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\cmd#1{\zcmd#1s}
\def\zcmd#1{\csname zcmd#1\endcsname}
\expandafter\def\csname zcmdx\endcsname_#1{A_{#1}\zcmd}
\expandafter\def\csname zcmdy\endcsname_#1{B_{#1}\zcmd}
\expandafter\def\csname zcmd*\endcsname{*\zcmd}
\expandafter\def\csname zcmd.\endcsname{\ldots\zcmd}
\expandafter\def\csname zcmds\endcsname{}

\begin{document}

$\cmd{x_1}$

$\cmd{x_1*}$

$\cmd{*y_1}$

$\cmd{x_1}$

$\cmd{x_1.x_n*y_1.y_n}$

\end{document}
```